# Astro Intellisense

Tags: plugins, astrojs

I'm doing one of a Youtube's tutorial. Once again I have a problem with Astro plugin. Many tutors have hints like `astro:content` when they are trying to import `getCollection` but my intellisense haven't it on a list. I don't know what's the problem. I installed the same plugin, it's a fresh VScode instance but there's not `astro:content` hint.

We could think, maybe tutorial is outdated but I can find in documentation that's i.e. `astro:content` is still in use.

Do I have to turn on some option to make it work? It's not a big deal to write it by hand but I thought those plugins are made for something. Any help what should I do?

[That's how my hints looks like in an editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szvxw.png)

I have installed astro plugin on a fresh VSCode but some hints are still missing.

Comment: Have you run the dev server yet? The `astro:content` types are added once dev runs or you run `astro sync`

Comment: `astro sync` helped! Thank you.